# Adding text from specific instance of div to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm trying to add some text to a textarea when a user clicks on an edit link. The user will click the edit link, which will then show a pop-up box with a textarea that shows the user their current comment.

There are going to be multiple instances of `.comment-block` with various different texts, as this text will be a user input comment. I want to take the `.text` text from the specific `.comment-block` depending on which `.edit` link was clicked. So if one comment-block has the text of "hello" and the other has text of "world", i want to take either "hello" or "world" and put it in the textarea, depending on which edit link was clicked from within the parent comment-block.

Hope that makes sense.

```
<div class="comment-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img src="/graphics/blank-avatar.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <p>
                <span class="name">David Johnson</span>
                <span class="text">Nice selection of images! Well done!</span>
                <span class="edit">Edit</span>
            </p>
            <div class="date-posted">
                Posted at 14:10 on 23rd September 2014
            </div><!-- .date-posted -->
        </div><!-- .col-xs-10 -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .comment-block -->
```

The JS

```
$("span.edit").click(function() {
    //Get the text
    var text = $.trim($(".comment-block p span.text").text())

    //Create a text area selector (container, rather)
    var textarea = $("#community-message-alt");

    //Give the textarea a value
    $("textarea", textarea).val(text);

    textarea.show();
});
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).parent().find(".text").first().html();
    $("#ta1").html(text);
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eL5fr/)

Comment: Thanks, this works flawlessly. Any chance you can explain what you did there?

Comment: Sure: with $(this) you get the clicked element, so you go to its parent and find a "text" class element among their children. Once found, you get the first of them, and retrieve its html. Then, you just need to set the html to your textarea tag :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).prev(".text").text();
    var textarea = $("#community-message-alt");
    textarea.text(text);
    textarea.show();
});
```